# ODBC issue with SQL-Server date field when migrating from XP32 to Win7 64

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, 64-bit, odbc, sas

I am running an SQL pass-through query in SAS.

When I run it on my 32bit WinXP box, the date field in the final SAS table is numeric.

When I run it on my 64bit Win7 box, the date field in the final SAS table is character.

Has anybody else experienced this problem?  How can I get the 64bit version to always return numeric (preferably without changes to the code as we are migrating environments)?

Thanks
Rob

```
proc sql noprint;
  connect to odbc as remote (datasrc=xxx);
  create table table1 as 
  select *
  from connection to remote
  (
  select cast(date_created as date) as date,
         count(*) as count
  from mydb.dbo.mytable
  group by cast(date_created as date)
  order by date
  )
  ;
  disconnect from remote;
quit;
```

**SOLUTION:** Needed to install "SQL Server Native Client 10". Download the 64bit installation here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=16177

Then re-setup DSNs using that new driver and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: Needed to install "SQL Server Native Client 10". Download the 64bit installation here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=16177

Then re-setup DSNs using that new driver and that fixed it.